# Android app to replace pattern lock

Tags: android

I am working on an app in which is going to provide new way to unlock the android phone.I made the working prototype. Problem which I am facing is this I want my app to start when user click the power button, but android already have pattern lock and I want to replace this pattern lock by my app. Is there anyway to do this ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.